# Instant App and splits abi

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, realm, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to split apk for different processors in the Instant App, but I can not separate the module (it's the only one) and split the Instant App. I need to reduce the size of apk, but realm takes more than 4 Mb. Any ideas how to do this?
**`build.gradle`(Instant App)**
[image: **<code>build.gradle</code>(Instant App)**]

**`build.gradle`(base module)**
[image: **<code>build.gradle</code>(base module)**]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

Splits are now supported. See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/guides/config-splits.html).

But for realm, there is at least one other [issue.](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4820)

**Original answer:**

Not supported yet, but we're working on it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm waiting.(((

Comment: @Dast6Tino, I've updated my answer. Splits are now supported.

Comment: Hooray! Thank you)

Comment: As stated quoted on Android Developers, this needs whitelist approval from Google for the time being, please refer: https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/guides/config-splits.html

Comment: note the *Known issues* section, on top of the whitelist, ABI, language region sub-tags, and multi-dimen splits aren't fully supported yet.